# Event triggered styled component css change

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm only now switching to styled component and could not find an answer for this fairly simple logic: if the validation for a field fails, it should have red borders.

With classic CSS classes:

```
const validateMail = (e) => {
    let mail = e.target.value;
    if (!mailRegex.test(mail)) {
        e.target.classList.add("error");
        return;
    }
    e.target.classList.remove("error");
}
```

How can I do something similar to `e.target.classList.add("error")`? I assume I would have to, somehow, change this list to something that changes the style of the field to begin with. Here's the complete class of the input styled component that triggers this function:

```
const Field = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

const Label = styled.label`
    font: ${fonts.body1};
    font-size: .75rem;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
    font: ${fonts.body1};
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:focus {
        border: 1px solid ${palette.primary_blue};
    }
`;

function InputField(props) {
    return (
        <Field>
            <Label htmlFor={"txt" + props.name}>{props.name + ":"}</Label>
            <Input name={"txt" + props.name} onKeyUp={props.onKeyUp}></Input>
        </Field>
    );
}

export default InputField;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've identified, styled components don't follow the classic class list paradigm. There are several ways to achieve the result you're after. I've demonstrated 2.

### Approach 1: Pass a prop to the styled component.

You can pass a custom `isValid` prop to the styled component like this:

```
<Input
  isValid={isValid}
  name={"txt" + props.name}
  onKeyUp={props.onKeyUp}
/>
```

You can then add conditional rendering logic inside the styled component based on how the prop is evaluated.

Note that the following arrow function in the styled component definition (in place of `styled.input`) ensures that the prop is treated as a component prop and not as an actual DOM element attribute (which would not be valid markup and could cause errors):

```js
const Input = styled(({
  isValid,
  ...props
}) => <input {...props} />)`
  border: 1px solid ${({ isValid }) =>
  isValid ? `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` : `red`)};

  /* ... the rest of your styles... */
`;
```

For a live example of the above, see this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hugle-g1vg7?file=/src/InputField.js). Note line 41 where `isValid` is being set to `false` as a stand-in for actual validation logic. Try changing it to `true` and you'll see that the border color changes.

---

### Approach 2: Create 2 separate styled components for valid and error states:

```js
const Input = styled.input`
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  /* ... the rest of your styles... */
`;

const ErrorInput = styled(Input)`
  border-color: red;
`;
```

```
const StyledInput = isValid ? Input : ErrorInput;

return (
  <Field>
    <Label htmlFor={"txt" + props.name}>{props.name + ":"}</Label>
    <StyledInput
      name={"txt" + props.name}
      onKeyUp={props.onKeyUp}
    />
  </Field>
);
```

Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-meitner-p6kbx?file=/src/InputField.js) of this approach. Same as with the first approach, see line 45 for hard-coded `isValid` value.

### Note about transitions

I prefer the first solution because it allows for smooth transitions between changing values (like with classes). The second approach works fine for static rendered elements, but it will basically destroy/create a new element on the fly when the component reference changes from `Input` to `ErrorInput`. If you want smooth transitions then you should use the first approach.

Comment: Note that for the working examples, I had to create stand-in values for the `fonts` and `palette` theme objects as well as `InputField` component props.

Comment: Great going the second approach. Didn't think of it. What I did instead was to style the component based on its state- which I'm not sure is a good idea.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "style the component based on its style" but I'm glad I could help. :) The 2nd approach in my answer is certainly clean to look at code-wise, but like I said... Big caveat that it won't give you a smooth transition between the two color states if that's something that you need. Both approaches are good to know about and I've found them both to come in handy quite a bit.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the typo. I meant "style the component based on its state"

Comment: Ah gotcha. Hey if it works, it works... but yeah the approaches in my answer are my go-to. I know there are even more ways to accomplish the goal, but the above are, to my knowledge, the most logical within the styled components paradigm.

Comment: Side note, a label’s `htmlFor` attribute should point to a form element’s `id` value and not a `name` value. Just change the input `name` attribute to `id` and you should be good to go.